# Formulating an equation for combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a set $S$ of $n$ items, $S = \{ S_1, S_2, ..., S_n \}$. Each item $S_i$ is associated with some value $\alpha_i$. Now suppose I want to put the items in a bag, with the constraint that the bag can only take in $k$ items at a time.

I want to write out an equation that sums up the configurations, wherein a configuration is given by the product: $\prod$ $\alpha_i${$S_i$ is in the bag} $(1-\alpha_i)${$S_i$ is *not* in the bag}.

For example, if $k=1$, the first group of products would be the case when $S_1$ was chosen to be put in the bag, the second group of products is the case when $S_2$ was chosen to be put in the bag, etc.

$sum = (\alpha_1) (1- \alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)...(1-\alpha_n) + (1-\alpha_1)(\alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)...(1-\alpha_n) + ... + (1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(\alpha_n)$

For $k=2$, the first group of products could be the case when $S_1$ and $S_2$ were chosen to be put in the bag. The second group of products represents the case when $S_1$ and $S_3$ were chosen to be put in the bag, etc. This would produce a total of $n \choose 2$ sums.

$sum = (\alpha_1) (\alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)...(1-\alpha_n) + (\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(\alpha_3)...(1-\alpha_n) + ... + (1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(\alpha_{n-1})(\alpha_n)$

and so each product would be a configuration of $n$ items taken $k$. 
I'd like to know if there's a better/ more compact way to write this. Any insight would definitely help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a representation which uses the following notation which is quite common in combinatorics.
\begin{align*}
[n]\ \ &\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{the set }\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\text{ for }n\in\mathbb{N}\\
\binom{S}{k}&\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{the set of }k\text{- element subsets of }S
\end{align*}
See for instance the section *notation* in R.P. Stanleys *[Topics in Algebraic Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf)*.

A formulation of OPs example using this notation could be

> Let $S=\{S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n\}$ be a set of $n$ items. We associate to each item $S_i,1\leq i\leq n$ a weight $\alpha_i$  with  $0\leq \alpha_i\leq 1$. For each $k\ (0\leq k\leq n)$ we consider *$k$-size bags* which contain $k$ pairwise different items $S_i$ from $S$.
>
> For a specific $k$-size bag let the $k$-subset  $A\in \binom{[n]}{k}$ be the corresponding index set. The *price* of a $k$-size bag  is then given as
>   \begin{align*}
> \prod_{i\in A} \alpha_i \prod_{j\in [n]\setminus A}(1-\alpha_j)
> \end{align*}
>   The price of *all* possible $k$-size bags is therefore
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{A\in\binom{[n]}{k}}\prod_{i\in A} \alpha_i \prod_{j\in [n]\setminus A}(1-\alpha_j)
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! The closed formula for my example (see edit) would therefore be $\sum_{A \in {S \choose k}} \prod_{i \in A} \alpha_i \prod_{j \in {S \setminus A}  }(1-\alpha_j)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @meraxes: $A\in\binom{S}{k}$ means that e.g. $A=\{S_2,S_5, S_6\}$ and in that case $\prod_{i\in A_i}\alpha_i=\alpha_{S_2}\cdot\alpha_{S_5}\cdot\alpha_{S_6}$ which is not intended. We need instead $A=\{2,5,6\}$, since we refer to the *indices* $i$ of the elements $S_i\in S$. That's why the representation $\binom{[n]}{k}$ is the correct one, as it refers to the index subsets. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks, that's correct. But what if I wrote it as $\sum_{A \in {S \choose k}} \prod_{S_i \in A} \alpha_i \prod_{S_j \in {S \setminus A}  }(1-\alpha_j)$  instead? Would that be correct as well? I just want it to be as intuitive as possible.

Comment: @meraxes: I appreciate your intention to be as intuitive as possible. But we should try to not overload the meaning of symbols or formulas. Your proposal is not correct, since the product symbol $\prod_{S_i\in A}\alpha_i$ declares $S_i$ to be used as indices, but the index $S_i$ does not occur. It is more appropriate to keep the symbolism as simple as possible and provide instead some glueing text which helps to better see what's going on. I've added an example in my answer which might be useful. Regards,

Comment: Alright, I understand. However, the problem now becomes a function of $n$ rather than $S$ which is not exactly what I want. I was thinking of turning $\alpha_i$ into $\alpha_{S_i}$, but it might as you say, overload the meaning of the symbol. I'm sorry for being persistent with this, and I appreciate your patience in replying.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a compact way to write the sum over all $k$'s of your products: it's just 1. This is because the products are the terms in the expansion of $\prod_i\bigl(\alpha_i+(1-\alpha_i)\bigr)=\prod_i1=1$. Likewise, if you want to restrict to adding up the configurations with exactly $k$ elements selected, then the sum would be the coefficient of $x^k$ in the product $\prod_i\bigl(\alpha_ix+(1-\alpha_i)\bigr)$, which is commonly denoted $[x^k]\prod_i\bigl(\alpha_ix+(1-\alpha_i)\bigr)$.